# Parse realm model using jackson

Tags: android, json, jackson, realm

Getting unknown key while converting realm model into json object using jackson library.

Here is my realm model instance.

```
    public class RecordData extends RealmObject {

    public RecordData() {

    }

    private FormData formData;

    @Nullable
    @JsonProperty("values")
    private RealmList<Values> values;

    @Nullable
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private String value;
}
```

Code for converting realm model to json object.

```
JSONObject recordDataJsonObject = new JSONObject(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(formData.getRecordData()));
```

Output  from parse json :

```
{"loaded":true,"managed":false,"valid":true,"value":"fdfdf","values":[]}
```

Realm version : `io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.1`

Rxjava version : `'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.6'`

Jackson version : `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.6`

Why i am getting loaded, managed and valid boolean values ?

Comment: Can you post code of `getRecordData()` ?

Comment: getRecordData() method return only RecordData realm model instance

Comment: Aren't you making any `Realm.where().findAll()` query? I need to see that code to verify if you're running into a similar issue that I solved.

Comment: That dose not make any sense, these boolean values are realm object internal fields. but it should not came in json.

Answer (score 0):

Write response from ObjectMapper, you have to do this:

```
public static String getJsonFromObject() {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = ObjectMapperHelper.getObjectMapperInstance();
        String jsonString = null;
           try {
            jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(formData.getRecordData());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonString != null ? jsonString : "";
    }
```

and get your response in JsonObject :

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject().getJSONObject(getJsonFromObject());
     } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Happy coding!!

Comment: I have used the same above but issue is there.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it using Gson parsing library.

```
JSONObject recordDataJsonObject = new JSONObject(new Gson().toJson(formData.getRecordData()));
```

Its not return unknown key. Output is here.

```
{"value":"fdfdf","values":[]}
```

Hope you will find this solution if you are facing same case.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"loaded", "managed", "valid"})
public class RecordData extends RealmObject {

    public RecordData() {

    }

    private FormData formData;

    @Nullable
    @JsonProperty("values")
    private RealmList<Values> values;

    @Nullable
    @JsonProperty("value")
    private String value;
}
```

Another option is to use `@RealmClass public class RecordData implements RealmModel`.

Comment: Using JsonIgnoreProperties would be batter option. But @RealmClass annotation is already added in my class.

Comment: The point is the `implements RealmModel` instead of `extends RealmObject`, but I think the ignore properties is easier