# Gson not serializing values

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

this is my Json response..

```
{"averageYield":15.0,"maxYield":15.0,"personalYield":100.0}
```

I am using Gson to serialize this Json, but it's storing values as 0 for all fields.

this is my Model class.

```
public class GetYieldComparisonResponse extends RealmObject {

    @SerializedName("averageYield")
    private double averageYield;

    @SerializedName("maxYield")
    private double maxYield;

    @SerializedName("personalYield")
    private double personalYield;

    public double getAverageYield() {
        return averageYield;
    }

    public void setAverageYield(double averageYield) {
        this.averageYield = averageYield;
    }

    public double getMaxYield() {
        return maxYield;
    }

    public void setMaxYield(double maxYield) {
        this.maxYield = maxYield;
    }

    public double getPersonalYield() {
        return personalYield;
    }

    public void setPersonalYield(double personalYield) {
        this.personalYield = personalYield;
    }
}
```

I am using Realm to store Data, but the storage values are 0 for every field.

```
GetYieldComparisonResponse getYieldComparisonResponse = GsonUtils.fromGson( basicResponse.getResponse(), GetYieldComparisonResponse.class );
```

this is my GsonUtils.java

```
//  This Class is useful for mapping Json into Java Objects and vice versa.
public class GsonUtils {

    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();

    //  This will Convert Java Objects into JSON String...
    public static String toGson(Object object) {
        return gson.toJson( object );
    }

    //  Gives Java Objects from JSON
    public static <T> T fromGson(String json, Class<T> type) {
        return gson.fromJson( json, type );
    }

    //  get Array...
    public static Object jsonToArray(String json, Type type) {
        return gson.fromJson( json, type );
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `basicResponse` of and what type does `basicResponse.getResponse()` return?

Comment: it's Json Response. {"averageYield":15.0,"maxYield":15.0,"personalYield":100.0} this one.

Comment: I see no *storing values as 0 for all fields.* in this response.

Comment: @Antoniossss I am using realm, so when it serializes json to objects, gson makes all values 0.

Comment: @AviPatel You have not answered my question. `Json Response` is probably not a type since it contains a space. And we need the package aswell.

Comment: No bro, json response gives json. and it maps that response to Objects. I am doing this for all my apis. and works perfectly.

Comment: Well, I tried, but it is not [mcve]. We do not know what type `RealmObject` is aswell.

Comment: okay forget about ReamObject, because it does not matter at all. my main concern is gson is not mapping my response and yes RealmObject has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jackson cannot serialize an my realm object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54924580/jackson-cannot-serialize-an-my-realm-object)

Comment: And @GolovPavel did prove that GSON, in the limits of the provided information, is not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It works perfectly if I do something like this:

```
GetYieldComparisonResponse getYieldComparisonResponse = GsonUtils.fromGson( "{\"averageYield\":15.0,\"maxYield\":15.0,\"personalYield\":100.0}", GetYieldComparisonResponse.class );
```

Maybe the problem in your response?

Comment: I dont think so, this should be the problem, because what you are doing is same as basicResponse.getResponse() does.

Comment: this didnot help as well.